# Alignment of P, UL, and TABLE using CSS 'padding-left' on any browser

Tags: html, css

In the html (with embedded css) below, the Ls, the Ts, and the Cs in 'Line', 'Title', and 'Cell' are aligned when displayed with Google Chrome, with Firefox, and with Safari.

They are not aligned when displayed with Internet Explorer. On IE the Ts are indented farther than the rest.

How can I modify the three-line css to make the three parts aligned under any browser?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=UTF-8>
<title>My Title</title>
<style type="text/css"><!-- 
body       { margin-left:   3em; }
p,ul,table { padding-left:  5em; }
 --></style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Heading One</h2>
<p>
    Line 1<br />
    Line 2<br />
</p>

<h2>Heading Two</h2>
<p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <b>Title C</b>
            <ul><li>Item C1</li><li>Item C2</li></ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <b>Title D</b>
            <ul><li>Item D1</li><li>Item D2</li></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</p>

<h2>Heading Three</h2>
<p>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Cell 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
    </table>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a reset stylesheet to ensure all browsers are starting with the same styles. Or at the very least just add

```
* { margin:0;padding:0;}
```

You will then need to specify some top and bottom padding but it will remove your issue.